# Set Bootstrap Accordion with specific id

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I have got a table shows a number of Errors in each the order. Each row shows how many errors in the specific order. I would like to add a See button at the end of the row and when a user clicks it, that row will expand like an accordion and shows error list.

```
 OrderId    Order From   Number of Error    Button
 ---------------------------------------------------
     1          A              4             See
     2          B              3             See
     3          C              2             See
```

When a user click See button on row 2

```
 OrderId    Order From   Number of Error    Button
 ---------------------------------------------------
     1          A              4             See
     2          B              3             See
     Error 1- 
     Error 2-
     Error 3-
     3          C              2             See
```

I couldn't figure out how to associate/link row with related error

```
 @{int i = 0;}
 @foreach (var item in Model.OrderList)
 {
     i++;
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ID)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(FROM)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(NumberOfError)
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
<a class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="collapse" href="#@i" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
controls="multiCollapseExample:@i">Toggle</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="collapse multi-collapse" id="@i">
                <td colspan="3">
                    Error 1
                    Error 2
                    Error 3
                </td>
            </tr>

enter code here
```

I know that i need to set anchor href="#" tag  to class="collapse multi-collapse" id="", but Bootstrap doesn't like if i start with number like "1abc" or "abc:1". I can't start with number or use ":" inside the id or href.

I tired "abc@{i}" it says i is variable can't use like that
tried this "abc:@i" no error but didn't work, also ":@iabc" or just "@i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show hide the next tr if you are creating tr.
It is simple with jquery to toggle that next tr.

```
@{int i = 0;}
 @foreach (var item in Model.OrderList)
 {
     i++;
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(ID)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(FROM)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(NumberOfError)
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="changeToggle(this)">See <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" ></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr class="collapse" style="display:none;">
            <td colspan="3">
                Error 1
                Error 2
                Error 3
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
<script>


function changeToggle(btn){
        $(btn).find(i).removeClass("fa-arrow-up");
        $(btn).find(i).removeClass("fa-arrow-down");
    if($(btn).closest( "tr" ).next().css('display') == 'none'){
        $(btn).find(i).addClass("fa-arrow-down");
        $(btn).find(i).removeClass("fa-arrow-up");
    }else{
        $(btn).find(i).removeClass("fa-arrow-down");
        $(btn).find(i).addClass("fa-arrow-up");
    }
    $(btn).closest( "tr" ).next().toggle();
}

    </script>
```

Comment: Also you can add animate property of toggle.

Comment: Thanks Ali.. Great help. Also i just fixed it before your reply with this code. href="#RowToggle-@i "  I don't know why but some how it is ok with "-@i"

Comment: My solution didn't work when I uploaded the website to the server. It opens accordion but collapses it after without clicking. I mean auto close. Not sure why. Anyway, I used your code above and it workes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Ali.  one more question pls. I would like to change the arrow style when the accordion is close arrow is down when the user clicked and accordion is on, the arrow will turn up.  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm " onclick="changeToggle(this)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" ></i></button>  I know in Jquery i could do it like $("#btn i") but because i used "this" in the line i can't use this way.. Can you help me pls

Comment: If you have <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" ></i> in the button so you have to check the tr is shown or hidden so you need this. $(btn).closest( "tr" ).next().css('display') == 'none'. Use this in if condition and if it is true then add class to $(btn).find("i").addClass("fa-arrow-down"); and remove class $(btn).find("i").removeClass("fa-arrow-up");

Comment: I edit the answer. Kindly check that and try this. I hope this will work fine.